# Windsor composite lifestyle for asp.net process

Tags: asp.net, castle-windsor, servicebus, masstransit

I have an asp.net process which also consumes messages from a servicebus (MassTransit). For webrequests my database session is resolved with a PerWebRequest lifestyle.

But when the process consumes a message from MassTransit I need the database session to have another lifestyle, as no HttpContext is available.

I have made this:

```
    public class PerRequestLifeStyleManager : ILifestyleManager
{
    readonly PerWebRequestLifestyleManager perWebRequestLifestyleManager;
    readonly PerThreadLifestyleManager perThreadLifestyleManager;

    public PerRequestLifeStyleManager()
    {
        perWebRequestLifestyleManager = new PerWebRequestLifestyleManager();
        perThreadLifestyleManager = new PerThreadLifestyleManager();            
    }

    public void Init(IComponentActivator componentActivator, IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        perWebRequestLifestyleManager.Init(componentActivator, kernel, model);
        perThreadLifestyleManager.Init(componentActivator, kernel, model);
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context)
    {
        return GetManager().Resolve(context);
    }

    public bool Release(object instance)
    {
        return GetManager().Release(instance);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GetManager().Dispose();
    }

    ILifestyleManager GetManager()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            return perWebRequestLifestyleManager;
        }

        return perThreadLifestyleManager;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me, if this is the right way to go? And if it isn't, what is?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have just updated the question with some code that seems to work (before it was untested). I still am eager to know if this - seen from a Windsor perspective - is safe and sound.

Comment: A good place to check, would be the MassTransit mailing list. http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss I think Dru has enough experience with Castle that he could lead you in the right direction but I surely don't. I haven't touched it ;)

Comment: I've been there, but only searching through it. I thought it was a little too much a cross over between Windsor and MassTransit to be relevant :) ... But thanks for the tip, I'll post it over there!

Comment: There is some discussion about session management here: http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/4be42a6319ce66ff/6f28a2eeea52278a?lnk=gst&q=windsor+lifestyle#6f28a2eeea52278a ... what I don't know though is how you make a custom lifestyle, that is based on those two before/after callbacks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using one of the [hybrid lifestyles](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/06/hybrid-lifestyles-in-windsor.html).

Comment: This is just perfect, thanks! Wish I had thought of hybrid instead of composite :)

Comment: do you know a way to do this with castle.windsor 3.0

Comment: @maxlego : yes, upgrade those hybrid lifestyles to Windsor 3.0, then send me a pull request.

Comment: @maxlego Hybrid lifestyles for Windsor 3 : https://nuget.org/packages/Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles

Answer (score 3):

By using the Castle Windsor extension, you should just be able to have your ISession as a dependency on the constructor of the consumer class. That way, the container will manage the lifecycle of the ISession, and dispose of it once the consumer is disposed by MT.

If you need even more control, you can look at how the WindsorConsumerFactory is implemented to wrap the resolution and release of the consumer class instance around the delivery of the message to the consumer.

If you need to inject something beyond that, you can also use an interceptor:

[Unit of work when using MassTransit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569320/unit-of-work-when-using-masstransit/5572031#5572031)

Comment: Thanks for answering here! I am using the Windsor extension and it works great. I believe that the Before/AfterConsumingMessage interception methods would be the easiest way to go to implement a custom Windsor lifestyle. But I wonder, does it always only consume one message at a time? And if not how can I know which message I am before and after at a given time?

Comment: A new consumer is created and released for each message received. A consumer's Consume method is called once for a single message during the life of the consumer. So I typically make the ISession a transient that gets disposed with the release of the consumer.

Comment: Ok. But then I get the same problems as oll has is in this thread http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/4be42a6319ce66ff/6f28a2eeea52278a?lnk=gst&q=windsor+lifestyle#6f28a2eeea52278a ... that you want the same ISession to be given to services longer down in the dependency chain. I'll open a topic on your mailing list :)

Comment: I have posted here http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f25db709c8395ef2 with what is actually my main question left now. Thanks for your help so far!